# Does spring boot support using both properties and yml files at the same time?

Tags: java, yaml, configuration-files, spring-boot, properties-file

I have a spring boot application and I want to use both a yml file for my application properties and also a plain application-${profile}.properties file set to configure my application.

So my question is can this be done and if so, how do you configure spring boot to look for both the yml file and the properties and merge them into one set per environment?

As to why I want/need to use both, it is because I like the flexibility and ease of use of yml files but an internal component (for encryption) requires using the properties file set.

I did see this point being made [YAML files can’t be loaded via the @PropertySource annotation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-external-config-yaml-shortcomings)

but nothing stating whether both can be used together.

Please provide detailed configuration (XML or Java config) on how to get this working.

TIA,

Scott

Answer (score 66, accepted):

I can answer my own question, as it just works as you would expect.  The application.yml file and the appropriate application-${profile}.properties both get loaded and merged into the environment. Spring boot just makes this work naturally.

Comment: I would suggest the reference documentation be updated to clarify if this answer is correct.  Right now the language in the guide makes it sound like its either or but not both.   Let me know if I should open up a JIRA ticket to get this updated.

Comment: I concur, this is why I have decided to Google the matter and hence arrived here :)

Comment: @ScottC. is correct .both application.yml and application-{profile}.properties are getting merged.

Comment: What about if you have both `application.yml` and `application.properties`?

Comment: u can keep both files but the properties files loads later and can overwrite the values if same is defined in the yml file as well.

Comment: @OrangeDog `application.properties` > `application.yml`, meaning yml loads first and properties later. Any `application-profile.properties` will be added even later. This is a nice way to override values in `application.properties` IMO.

Answer (score 51):

**Yes You can use both at same time in same project.**

- When you use both YML and properties at same time, say for example
  application.yml and application.properties at same time in same
  project, **first application.yml will be loaded, later

  application.properties will be loaded**.
- Important point to be noted is that if application.yml and
  application.properties have **same keys** for example in
  **application.yml** has **spring.app.name = testYML** and
  **application.properties** has **spring.app.name = testProperties** **at same
  time in same project**, then application.yml value will be overwritten
  by application.properties value since it is loading at last.
- And the    value in **spring.app.name = testProperties**.

Comment: Your sentence "first application.yml will be loaded **later**, application.properties will be loaded." should be "first application.yml will be loaded, application.properties will be loaded **later**.", right?

Comment: Yes you are right

Answer (score 10):

Yes, you can run both without doing any configuration.

In Spring Boot, it picks .properties or .yaml files in the following sequences :

1. application-{profile}.{properties|yml}
2. application.{properties|yml}

Comment: This is only correct in order of priority but not in order of what is loaded first. Any application-profile.properties is loaded after application.properties. This is how you override values. Also yml is read before properties if you so happens to have both.  Example application-profile.properties > application.properties > application.yml, where > (greater than) means left side is greater than right side.